# How to fix this inner join SQL query? instead of 1 count() is returning 3

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to get the data of the last seven days from two tables, but I have a little error.

My initial query is this:

```
with recursive dates as (
            select curdate() as dte, 1 as lev
            union all
            select dte - interval 1 day, lev + 1
            from dates
            where lev < 7
           )
      select DATE_FORMAT(d.dte, '%d') AS date, count(c.id) AS cards, count(mc.id) AS mymyv_cards
      from dates d 
      left join
           cards c
           on c.publicated = 1 and
              str_to_date(left(c.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') >= d.dte and
              str_to_date(left(c.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') < d.dte + interval 1 DAY
      left join
           mymyv_cards mc
           on mc.publicated = 1 and
              str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') >= d.dte and
              str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') < d.dte + interval 1 day
      group by d.dte
```

And I get this result:

[image]

The problem is that the *mymyv_cards* isn't correct, because I have only one record.

If I execute this query:

```
      with recursive dates as (
            select curdate() as dte, 1 as lev
            union all
            select dte - interval 1 day, lev + 1
            from dates
            where lev < 7
           )
      select DATE_FORMAT(d.dte, '%d') AS date, count(mc.id) AS mymyv_cards
      from dates d 
      left join
           mymyv_cards mc
           on mc.publicated = 1 and
              str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') >= d.dte and
              str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') < d.dte + interval 1 day
      group by d.dte
```

I get the correct result:

[image]

I don't know why this is happening, I'm not sure if this is because of the *inner join* or not.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output corresponding to that input data. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data it's difficult to say for sure what's wrong. I think
`dates d inner join cards c` is causing this. And it's a valid outcome. There might be three rows in cards table for a row in dates table. So when you are left joining `mymyv_cards` with the result of previous join it's getting three rows for a single row in `mymyv_cards` table.

You can use distinct only to count unique ids.

```
with recursive dates as (
            select curdate() as dte, 1 as lev
            union all
            select dte - interval 1 day, lev + 1
            from dates
            where lev < 7
           )
      select DATE_FORMAT(d.dte, '%d') AS date, count( distinct c.id) AS cards, count( distinct mc.id) AS mymyv_cards
      from dates d 
      left join
           cards c
           on c.publicated = 1 and
              str_to_date(left(c.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') >= d.dte and
              str_to_date(left(c.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') < d.dte + interval 1 DAY
      left join
           mymyv_cards mc
           on mc.publicated = 1 and
              str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') >= d.dte and
              str_to_date(left(mc.publication_date, 10), '%d-%m-%Y') < d.dte + interval 1 day
      group by d.dte
```

Comment: You are right, that was the problem and using *distinct* I could fix the error. Thanks!